# How to find any potential security issues in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Since I'm not an Php programmer I have to ask you, I have to challenge to investigate some source which is currently under attack. Its some local news site with custom cms inside. Its phg mysql under shared linux hosting env.

admin is registered on entering credentials in login form and those credentials are checked in db like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
        include 'db.php';

    $connection = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbName, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

        $queryString = "SELECT * FROM `Admins` WHERE `username` = '$user_name' AND password='$password'";
        $safeSelect = mysql_real_escape_string($queryString);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `Admins`
            WHERE `username` = '$user_name' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die('error making query');
    $affected_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($affected_rows == 1) {
        //add the user to our session variables
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user_name;
    header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/admin/index.php");
        exit;
        //print 'allowed';
        }
    else {
        print 'access is not allowed !!!';
    }
?>
```

Auth.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'db.php';
    if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
        die('to access these page you have to be registered user.
        <a href="/admin/login.php">log in</a>');
    }
?>
```

This session var is used on whole administration area to recognize registered user. 
Admin user edits and creates new content like this
edit.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include '/admin/db.php';
include '/admin/auth.php';
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $dbcnx = mysql_connect('localhost', $dbUser, $dbPass);
    mysql_select_db($dbName);
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])):
        // content will be updated with these
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $cats = $_POST['cats'];
        $newstext = $_POST['newstext'];

$sql = "UPDATE `News` SET
             `NewsText`='$newstext',
             `AID`='$aid',
         `imgID`='$imgID'
             WHERE `ID`='$id'";
 if (mysql_query($sql)) {
            echo('<p><b>content is succ. updated</b></p>');
        } else {
            die('<p>Error occured when updating content: ' .
                    mysql_error() . '</p>');
        }
else: // Allow user to edit content using ID=$id

            /* $aid = $_GET['aid']; */
             if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) == FALSE) {
                    echo "<h1>Page is not found</h1>";
                    session_destroy();
                return;
             }
                $id = $_GET['id'];
            }

$row = @mysql_query("SELECT `NewsText`, `Title`, `AID`, `imgID` FROM `News` WHERE `ID`='$id'");
            if (!$row) {
                die('<p>Db error: ' .
                        mysql_error() . '</p>');
            }
$row = mysql_fetch_array($row);
            $newstext = $row['NewsText'];
            $text = $row ['Title'];
            $authid = $row ['AID'];
            $imgID = $row ['imgID'];
            $newstext = htmlspecialchars($newstext);

//ommitting html form
?>
```

Basically I want to ask is there some security issue here.

Found solution here
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: Whole code have serious [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulneability

Comment: @safarov how would you fix these code

Comment: Read on to some PHP security best practices, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012315/php-security-best-practices

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of the login page? especially the login form and handling of it. Are passwords scrambled in the database? do you use salted passwords? is setting of $password escaped? as in mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Straight off the bat it looks like there is a SQL injection issue going on here. POST requests are being put straight into an SQL query which allows someone with a specially crafted POST request to execute any query pretty much on the server...

It might be worth looking at this...

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

No its not secure, its calling `mysql_real_escape_string` once on a string then not using that string in the actual query.

If your not a PHP programmer then why have you been asked to investigate this?

Comment: cause I need to fix these and after that move on other platform where I'm on home field. Mvc3 and Nhibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its vulnerable to sql injection

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

As pointed at by others there is a chance SQL injection. Though using mysql_real_escape_string also helps prevent sql injection, I would recommend leaving the whole mysql* behind and go for PDO which can use prepared statements for example